# Specifying file name and destination in get_thumbnail function of sorl thumbnail

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, sorl-thumbnail

I am using `sorl thumbnail` for the first time. I am working with [Low Level API](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#low-level-api-examples) and using the `get_thumbnail` method.

As per the [link](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#low-level-api-examples), I successfully used `im = get_thumbnail(my_file, '100x100', crop='center', quality=99)`, but I would like to specify the destination source location and the filename as well. Is that possible? How do I do that?

Comment: If you are talking about giving the thumbnail that is created from the source image its own filename and location - you can't. This information is generated by sorl and is what makes it so quick performance-wise

Comment: Ya, I am exactly asking that. Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. The path and filename are generated by sorl and directly relate to how the thumbnail paths and their files are cached, and stored.

If you look at the actual method in `sorl` that gets or creates the thumbnail:

https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/blob/master/sorl/thumbnail/base.py#L32

you'll see that the destinatation and filename of the created thumbnail is a hash value of the `source filename`, `source location`, `source dimensions` and `source options`. It creates this hash, checks the cache to see a value for that hash/key is present, if it is - return the path corresponding to that thumbnail, if not - generates the thumbnail, save it and cache the path.

Therefore changing the destination of the filename would mean you could no longer retrieve that thumbnail from the cache.

The only thing you can change is the root folder of where you want these files to be saved i.e. under `/cache/...` or `/thumbnails/...`

Comment: According to this answer, you can define your own function for filenames.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24992909/1977847

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can extend **'sorl.thumbnail.base.ThumbnailBackend'** override **_get_thumbnail_filename** method that handle destination filename and sign the new class to **THUMBNAIL_BACKEND** in settings.

Comment: Also here: https://micropyramid.com/blog/preserve-file-names-with-sorl-for-better-seo/

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.files.base import File

my_file = File(open('/path/to/file', 'rb')) # or my_file = open('/path/to/file', 'rb')
im = get_thumbnail(my_file, '100x100', crop='center', quality=99)
```

Comment: No willfill, this is not what I am asking. I need something for destination and not for source.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not fully understand your question due to my low level of English. pastylegs rights, you can not change the sorl generated path, but you may try to write own function for generate thumbnails path.(but I think this not good solution)